# Recognizing new words with Freeling

Tags: nlp, pos-tagger, freeling

I'm using Freeling to analyse text in Spanish, but I have a question when it comes to customize the used dictionary. The specific example is that the word

```
morelos
```

is a singular masculine noun but is being split in two words and classified as follows:

```
more morar VMM03S0 1 -  
los lo PP3MPA0 1 -
```

I've tried a wide variety of things from adding the word in the dictionary, which entry the following

```
morelos morelos NPMSS00
```

I've tried not using multiwords, but is also unsuccessful.

Can anyone recommend me what to do?

(Is there anywhere a comprehensive tutorial to understand use freeling?)

Comment: Clarification question: is it a proper name?  Because if it refers to the Mexican state, then does it work if you keep it capitalized?

Answer (score 2):

This is because the affixation module is considering this a clitic pronoun (morar+los)

You can deactivated affixation, or try to fine-tune the affixation rules.

There is comprehensive information about FreeLing in its user manual and in its user forums.  Check [FreeLing webpage](http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/freeling)